# Hinge on 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, unibody

I have a 2016 15" MacBook Pro and I want to know if it is normal that when I lift the lid, it moves more freely than I expect.

- In other words, if I gently push the lid without changing the opening angle, the lid moves and returns to its place.

Previously I had a MacBook Air, and this did not happen, that's causing me to worry.

Here is video showing [movement and hinge action for my MacBook Pro](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x79q01g)

Is this normal?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It sounds like when you are opening the lid only slightly, it's snapping back to it's place. Is that correct? It would help if you have make a brief video recording and share.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not normal and either the clutch mechanism has too much play or a mounting screw is loose or something fractured.

Although Apple changed the way the signal cables connect from the lid to the motherboard radically in the 2016 model, as compared to earlier models, the mechanical hinge mechanism is much the same as previously, and there should be no give in any lateral direction between the lid and the frame.

All clutches slip a little, but yours seems overly loose. Protect it and get a repair estimate from Apple are my recommendation. It may be covered for free or it might be a paid repair, but then you’ll know for sure.

Comment: the warranty expires and the repair is expensive. Do you think it's risky to keep the mac like this? or it is better to sell it? Thanks